# Using select statement as unit test data instead of specified data Oracle

Tags: oracle, unit-testing

I am new at Oracle unit testing. I have been trying to unit test procedures, which uses tables in its script. I want to use select statement for unit test (to have a single row of input instead of alot of rows). The problem is oracle sql developer unit testing automatically uses existing tables for testing and I do not wish to create more tables to test. Is there are way to do it? I tried writing a script in startup process but It sql developer just takes data from tables instead.

Script:

```
DECLARE SALARY NUMBER;    
COMMISION_PCT NUMBER;    
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER;    
    
BEGIN      
    select 8400 as salary, 0.2 as COMMISSION_PCT, 1001 AS EMPLOYEE_ID      
    INTO SALARY, COMMISION_PCT, EMPLOYEE_ID    
    FROM DUAL;      
END;
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem ??

Comment: Unless you change the procedure to use a CTE, which wouldn't really make sense if you're trying to test the procedure as it will really be used, it will still look at the tables. You could possibly replace the data in the existing tables before calling the procedure, but would need to either make sure nothing commits before you can rollback those changes afterwards, or have a back-up/export to restore from, or both. That could go wrong though, particularly if this is new to you. Why is creating new tables - in a separate schema for UT, say - a problem?

Comment: Its not exactly a problem its more time consuming. We have few packages with several procedures each that uses around 150 tables, so I was thinking of going around that. If its not possible then ok. Can you post that as an answer so I could upvote? :)

Comment: Well, MTO has covered that already *8-) As for creating tables, you can export from one schema and then import with just metadata into another schema, then add the few rows you need?

Comment: @Rimvydas, I would never touch the original data for QA purposes. I'd rather use Datapump for creating a QA schema using `content=metadata_only`. If your procedures, packages and functions are not using schema.table_name notation for referencing the objects, the code will work just fine in your new schema. If the code is updated frequently, instead of deploying the code in your new QA schema, you might use SYNONYMS for them.

Comment: Yes I also realised that, also I was thinking of actually copying packages and tables to unit testing schema and test there, but I realised that alot of our procedures use tables from other schemas that I do not have permissions to.... I am still searching for that alternative answer.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that you **NEVER** use a `COMMIT` statement in any procedure (and preferably that you have development and production servers so that, just in-case a mistake is made, you are not testing on your live, customer data).

In your test setup you can delete all the rows from the tables and put in your sample data that you are going to use to test with:

```sql
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM table1;
  DELETE FROM table2;

  INSERT INTO table1 (salary, commission_pct, employeed_id)
  SELECT 8400, 0.2, 1001 FROM DUAL;

  INSERT INTO table2 (employeed_id, col1, col2)
  SELECT 1001, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1001, 2, 2 FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Then you can run the tests on your procedure using the sample data.

Finally, in the tear-down you can `ROLLBACK` the changes to remove your test data and restore any previous data:

```sql
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

*(You must **NOT** `COMMIT` the changes in the procedures you are testing; otherwise you will `COMMIT` the test data and `ROLLBACK` will only return to the last `COMMIT`. When you want to `COMMIT` from a 3rd-party application then most applications can be set to automatically commit the transaction when you close it rather than using explicit `COMMIT` statements.)*